# Cast Device Development

Tags: android, casting, operating-system, hardware, android-tv

I want to develop a casting device, something like ChromeCast or Roku,  to cast content from YouTube and Netflix to the device, I need to know more about which are the available operative systems and which are the hardware(processors and peripherals) for that OS, I was looking for use Android TV, but I want to use an official version, exist some way to contact with google or something, for making the development official?.

Also, I made a proof of concept using a raspberry pi and raspicast, searching about that I found 2 devices (miracast and anycast) and they have their own operative system, anyone have information about this kind of devices and their software and hardware?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Google Cast SDK docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/) and the [Android TV docs](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start). That's all Google has to offer right now.

Comment: I already check those docs, they specify a lot of things about the software development for those platforms, but I need more information about hardware development